# Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

Using `react-navigationv5` I have a warning when trying to set the state:

```js
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState<Node<number>>(new Value(0));
  const scale = Animated.interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8],
  });
  const animatedStyle = { transform: [{ scale }] };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={(props) => {
          // FIXME - settingProgress should not be done like this - this prompts big fat warning
          setProgress(props.progress);
          return <DrawerContent {...props} />;
        }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name={Screens.DRAWER_SCREENS}>
          {(props) => <DrawerScreensStack {...props} style={animatedStyle} />}
        </Drawer.Screen>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I am trying to set my progress in the component state from drawerContent to calculate some animation and pass that animation to DrawerScreensStack. It is working but I have a warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
    in DrawerView (at DrawerView.tsx:215)
```

How can I get rid of the warning and what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

At the end I removed local state and I have created a local variable to update style and warning is gone.

```js
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  let animatedStyle: Animated.AnimateStyle<ViewStyle> = {};
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        sceneContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
        drawerContent={(props) => {
          const scale = Animated.interpolate(props.progress, {
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [1, 0.85],
            extrapolate: Animated.Extrapolate.CLAMP,
          });
          animatedStyle = {
            transform: [
              {
                scale: scale,
              },
            ],
          };
          return <DrawerContent {...props} />;
        }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name={Screens.DRAWER_SCREENS}>
          {(props) => <DrawerScreensStack {...props} style={animatedStyle} />}
        </Drawer.Screen>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
};
```